# How to create "Delete And Continue" button on UI Component Form

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, uicomponent, adminform, custom-button

I'm new at Magento 2, and I'm trying to create a custom button on an UI Component form. But I don't know what to put in the `"actionName"` field of the button.

When I put the `"save, back, delete, save_and_continue"` it works, but I'm trying to call another controller that I made, that is `"SaveHeader"` but I don't know where I configure this...

I want to use this button as a **"delete and continue"**...
Is there any way to create a custom "action name" for the button ?

My intention is only to delete a few fields of the form and continue editing.

```
<button name="delete_header" >
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="buttonClasses" xsi:type="string">custom-button-class</item>
                <item name="actions" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="targetName" xsi:type="string">api_data_form.api_data_form_data_source</item>
                        <item name="actionName" xsi:type="string">SaveHeader</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <displayAsLink>false</displayAsLink>
            <title translate="true">Delete Header</title>
        </settings>
    </button>
```